# mysql_real_escape_string method really slow (nearly 1 second)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

i do have a Query here (PHP with Zend Framework on a MySQL Database) using one POST Parameter as an argument in an SQL Statement.

So i do have a local XAMPP Installation on my development machine and the runtime of this small Script ist something like 150ms no matter if i pass the argument with or without using mysql_real_escape_string() on that argument before.

Then i do have a virtual server with BitNami-WAMP-Stack installed. When i run the Script there (100% same database content) it takes around 260ms without mysql_real_escape_string, this is not as "fast" (i know that 150ms isn't really fast at all) as my local machine but would be okay. But if i do add only one mysql_real_escape_string() to the argument from the POST variable the whole thing takes 1.2 seconds.

And i further noticed that every call to mysql_real_escape_string makes the script run around 1 second slower on the virtual server. On my local machine this does not have any effect.

How can this be? Is this a MySQL Setup thing or a PHP.ini thing or what? Because i do have the 100% same database and PHP source on both machines i guess it can only be parametrization?

Thanks for any help in advance!

**EDIT:**

So here is what i do, first connecting the DB (in Bootstrap.php):

```
$GLOBALS["db"]= new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
            'host'     => "localhost",
            'username' => "user",
            'password' => "password",
            'dbname'   => "database"
            ));
```

And then later in want to query the database:

```
global $db;

$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($id) );

$db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$db->fetchAll($query);
```

I just made another test: when i add this simple test-line to my code, it makes the script ~600ms slower on the virtual machine:

```
mysql_real_escape_string("TEST");
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for the query creation and execution? Also does the DB run on the same physical/virtual?

Comment: What is the size (in characters) of the string that you are escaping?

Comment: The String i am escaping is only an int database-id with a length of 2 to 5 digits

Comment: And yes, the DB runs on the same (localhost) machine in both setups

Comment: Is the database open/connected before you first try to call mysql_real_escape_string? What happens when you try to real escape a string second time? And what happens if you supply the second parameter -- $link_identifier?

Answer (score 0):

use prepared statements to do this:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html

Answer (score 0):

The long-term solution must be switching to prepared statements, that is right. An equivalent to `mysql_real_escape_string` for PDO connections seems to be `PDO::quote`:

http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.quote.php

Any disadvantages compared to a `mysql_real_escape_string` based solution?

Comment: I believe that just adding quotes (as this function does) is not enough. mysql_real_escape_string() will actually escape any special characters with a '\' as it prevents mysql from executing them. (correct me if i'm wrong)

Comment: the manual says that it also replaces special characters within the input string

Comment: PDO quote is roughly 20 times SLOWER than a regex escape() function.
It's a horrible function in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same delay on first call mysql_real_escape_string method, solution in my case was information from manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

"A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string() otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and FALSE is returned. If link_identifier isn't defined, the last MySQL connection is used."

The only thing missig was information about delay if connection is not estabilished.

In your case I suppose that if you are using PDO for connection then you should use PDO::quote. If you are using mysql_pconnect/mysql_connect then you can use mysql_real_escape_string  without delay.